# Trouble remembering import rules in Python

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

It's been a while since I have used Python and am stumbling already at a simple import!

statements.py:

```
str = "hello"
```

main.py:

```
import statements

print statements.str
```

Obviously the final program will have more going on, and the statements will be stuff like URLs. For this simple example however with both files sitting side by side in the same folder I get the following error on running main.py:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I know I am doing something terribly silly, but I can't see what it is. Searching around it looks fine. Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: You used the import correctly, but are importing a module without the `str` name. What does `print statements.__file__` tell you was imported?

Comment: Also, was the module already imported in your Python session before you added the name `str`? If so, you may need to restart or at least reload the module with `reload(statements)`.

Comment: That was it I'd say Martjin! Embarrassing to say the least :-P. Cheers all the same!

Comment: Nice that it works now, but maybe calling your variable the same as the builtin function str isn't ideal.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't normally be str. I was just using that as an example here -- all else was unchanged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the `import` statement correctly. The error then can be caused by either importing a different module with the same name, or by having altered the module after already having imported it.

You can check `print statements.__file__` to see what module Python found instead when importing, and you can use the [`reload()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) to ask Python to reload the module from disk if you altered it.